# Vector differentiation

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Here is a step in a differentiation I don't understand. Let $(x^1, ...,x^k), (y^1,...,y^k)$ denote two vectors with $y^i = y^i(x^1,....,x^k)$. Given 
$$ y^1(0,x^2,...,x^k) = 0$$
how can I reach the conclusion that
$$ {\partial (y^1,...,y^k) \over \partial (x^1,...,x^k)}= {\partial y^1 \over \partial x^1}{\partial (y^2 , ...,y^k) \over \partial (x^2,...,x^k) }$$

? Is it really multiplication on the RHS of the equation? I'm stumped by this.

Comment: Would you mind defining the notation $\frac{\partial(y^1,\cdots,y^k)}{\partial(x^1,\cdots,x^k)}$? It's been a while since I took multivariable calculus and I've forgotten a little bit of the notation.

Comment: Hi, could you clarify something for me?.
Is $(y^1, \dots, y^k)$ a vector of functions?, and also $(x^1, \dots, x^k)$?. I ask because you took $y^i(x^i)$, if $y$ isn't a function i'm not sure what it is.
If you read the problem in book, please write wich book is it.

Answer (score 2):

The conclusion is true if $x^1=0$. In fact notice that in that case
$$
\frac{\partial y^1}{\partial x^k} = 0 \qquad k>1
$$
and the result follows by the Laplace formula for the determinant:
$$ 
{\partial (y^1,...,y^k) \over \partial (x^1,...,x^k)}= \sum_{i=1}^k(-1)^{i+1}{\partial y^1 \over \partial x^i}{\partial (y^2 , ...,y^k) \over \partial (x^1,...,\hat{x^i},...,x^k) }
$$

Comment: Great, thank you! So is it $$ 
\left |{\partial (y^1,...,y^k) \over \partial (x^1,...,x^k)}\right |= ...
$$ (determinant) rather than $$ 
{\partial (y^1,...,y^k) \over \partial (x^1,...,x^k)}= ...
$$ that we are computing?